# Не могу разобраться как сделать так чтобы работал код

Tags: python

Код:

```
bounded_min(-5, 12, 13, lo=0, hi=255)
```

Выкидывает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import bounded_min
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bounded_min'
```

Comment: Питон не смог найти у себя модуль `bounded_min`, поэтому и выдал такую ошибку. Ищите у себя `bounded_min.py`

Comment: Где вы эту функцию взяли? Здесь вот https://ziginsider.github.io/pythonexx2/ её создают и используют без всяких модулей

Comment: Кирилл Малышев  ты сам попробуй

Comment: у тебя ошибку выдаст не определена переменная bounded_min

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, вынеси ф-цию bounded_min() в отдельный файл *.py (это же твоя ф-ция, да?). После уже импортируй *.py (import *.py) с функцией bounded_min() и используй её.
Если у тебя эта функция в основной программе, то импортировать её не надо (надеюсь, что у тебя не такого рода проблема).

Comment: При ответе избегайте вопросительных условных формулировок - "это же твоя ф-ция?", "надеюсь, что" и.т.п..